# Redux Saga - Callback to update local state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

How to update local state of component after disptach action ?

In my case, I show a popin based on component local state :

```
   <button onClick={() => this.setState({ popin: true })}>Open</button>
   <Popin hidden={!this.state.popin}>
      <form onSubmit={createItem})>
        <div className="popin-heading">...</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ popin: false })}>Close</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </Popin>
```

On submit click, createItem dispatch action catch in Saga :

```
function* watchCreateItem() {
  yield takeEvery('CREATE_ITEM', doCreateItem);
}

function* doCreateItem(values) {
  try {
    // Do POST API request
    const response = yield fetch('/create', { method: 'post', body: values });

    // Disptach action to store new item in redux store (by reducer)
    yield put(storeItem(response));

    /**
     * !!! Here, want to update 'state.popin = null' !!!
     */

  } catch (error) {
    showNotification(reponse.message, 'error');
  }
}
```

How to close popin after API post request is success ?

I would like to keep storing popin state in local component state and not in Redux store (with mapStateToPros)

Thanks.

Comment: Can your component tell that `create` has happened by looking at the value it gets back?  (e. g. can it discern the difference between a new item and a persisted item?)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I add a new reducer "popin" to manage open/close state.

Action creators :

```
function ShowPopinAction(current = 'default') {
  return { action: 'POPIN_STATE', current};
}

function HidePopinAction() {
  return ShowPopinAction(null);
}
```

Reducer :

```
function (state = {current: null}, action) {
  if (action.type === 'POPIN_STATE') {
    return {current: action.current}
  }

  return state;
}
```

And in my component :

```
<button onClick={ () => ShowPopinAction('createItem') }>Open</button>
<Popin hidden={this.props.current !== 'createItem'}>
  ....
  <button onClick={HidePopinAction}>Close</button>
</Popin>

connect( 
   state = > ({ current: state.popin.current }), 
   { ShowPopinAction, HidePopinAction } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which makes use of componentDidUpdate and mapStateToProps

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isShowPopin: false
  };
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { isFetchedItem: prevPropsisFetchedItem } = prevProps;
    const { isFetchedItem } = this.props;
    if (isFetchedItem !== prevPropsisFetchedItem) {
      this.setState({ isShowPopin: isFetchedItem });
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isFetchedItem: state.yourReducer.isFetched
  };
};
function mapDispatchtoProps() {
  return {
    //your dispatch to actions
  };
}
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(A);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question before read your answer. I am afraid to manage many values in Redux store just for Popin state. I have many popin for CRUD operations and I would need a Redux value for each one (edit item, delete item, create item ... )

Comment: According with the documentation the method componentWillReceiveProp is UNSAFE https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @cesarlarsson: Yes things in Reactjs have changed quite a lot, when I answered this question. Now you can make use of componentDidUpdate. Editing the answer